# Prevent Construction of object using new()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, new-operator

In the Unity game engine, all classes deriving from a MonoBehaviour class cannot be constructed with the new() operator, despite their default constructors being public. Doing so returns a warning in the Unity log and the object is not instantiated, leaving the reference null.

I'm curious how they managed to prevent the object from being created when the constructor is called. I did some research and heard that throwing an exception in the object's constructor can prevent its creation, so I tried it out myself and it worked when the exception was handled outside the constructor. However, I still do not understand how they actually instantiate the class using the correct method (`AddComponent<T>()`).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried?

Comment: What do you mean they cannot be constructed with `new`? Is there a compiler error or an exception?

Comment: @JohnSaunders He wants to restrict users creating a object with `new`. He is not having problem creating a new object.

Comment: @NirajDoshi: that is a likely interpretation, but I'd rather the OP tell me that. This will also inform future readers.

Comment: @JohnSaunders OP has already mentioned his curiosity over it

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice that. It's also not possible, so he should show us code which demonstrates the problem. Like `var x = new DerivedClass(); Debug.Assert(x == null);`

Comment: @Kimimaru Can you post that code that initializes an instance of that class using AddComponent<T>

Comment: This is the full error: `You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword. This is not allowed. MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent(). Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:.ctor() ItemClass:.ctor() inventoryV1:.ctor()`

And that definitely used to be a thing. Interestingly, I'm not getting that error in Unity 5 so they possibly removed it. As far as how they do it, based on the message it would seem that they're just throwing the exception in the MonoBehaviour constructor.

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks for the replies. I'm not actually trying to do anything in particular, but I'm just curious of how they might have handled this.

@CrappyCodingGuy has the warning message that's displayed when you attempt to instantiate a MonoBehaviour using new(). I'm assuming AddComponent() has some sort of factory method setup or uses Reflection to instantiate the object.

As for code to properly instantiate a MonoBehaviour in Unity, it goes like this (assume Item derives from MonoBehaviour):

Item myItem = this.gameObject.AddComponent<Item>();

This will return a reference to an Item.

Comment: Alot of the comments here neglect to take note of the many key points made by the OP.  1. This is Unity3D and not _plain c#_;  2. Trying to allocate via `new` a class derived from `MonoBehaviour`;  3. Unity3d **does not throw an exception** but rather **returns null**.  OP is asking how they managed it not _what's wrong with my code_. Code is not required because anyone using Unity can reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain vanilla C#, it is not possible for the `new` operator to return `null`. It will either return a valid non-null reference, or it will throw an exception.

Note, however, that Unity is not "plain vanilla C#". Unity is based on Mono (which in turn is based on .NET), but is customized for their own purposes.

Having control over the compiler and runtime means you can do a variety of non-standard things. Like, provide a mechanism to allow the `new` operator to return `null` as a result if it's being used with an invalid type (i.e. any subclass of `MonoBehavior`). And, for example, to provide an alternate allocation mechanism that `AddComponent<T>()` can use.

A detailed description of the inner workings of all this would be too broad for Stack Overflow (and I don't know the specifics off the top of my head anyway). But given that Mono is open-source, I assume the license is one of those that requires Unity's modifications of that open-source to also be made available. I.e. if you really wanted to know all the nitty gritty, you could just browse the actual source code and see how they do it, specifically.